How do I stop the label from moving
from tkinter import *
from math import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('550x320')
def p():
    x = str(floor(int(e1.get())/64)) + " Stacks + " + str(int(e1.get())%64) + " Items"
    Items = Label(root, text=x,font=('Arial 15'))
    Items.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=W) 
H = Label(root,text='Poopoo doodoo',font=('Arial 20'))
H.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=N)
l1 = Label(root, text = "Number: ")
l1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W,pady=2,padx=10)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=2)
but = Button(root,text='Submit',command=p)
but.grid(row=3,column=0)
root.mainloop()

H label keeps moving when I put higher number in entry, How do i stop it from moving beyond the edge of the window

not related to your problem, but you can use stacks, items = divmod(int(el.get()), 64)

You can simply change sticky=N to sticky=W in H.grid(...).  Also it is better to create Items once and update its text inside p().
from tkinter import *
from math import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('550x320')
def p():
    x = str(floor(int(e1.get())/64)) + " Stacks + " + str(int(e1.get())%64) + " Items"
    Items.config(text=x) # update text
    Items.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=W)
H = Label(root,text='Poopoo doodoo',font=('Arial 20'))
H.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W)  # changed N to W
l1 = Label(root, text = "Number: ")
l1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W,pady=2,padx=10)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=2)
but = Button(root,text='Submit',command=p)
but.grid(row=3,column=0)
Items = Label(root, font=('Arial 15')) # create label once
root.mainloop()


Your H label is moving because it's centered in an expanding column.
Both H and Items are being placed in column 2. Whenever you input a large enough number, Items gains some digits and therefore requires more space. This causes the column to grow wider, so H needs to move rightward to remain in the center.
There are lots of ways to fix this, but an easy one is just to put H in a different column:
from tkinter import *
from math import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('550x320')
def p():
    x = str(floor(int(e1.get())/64)) + " Stacks + " + str(int(e1.get())%64) + " Items"
    Items = Label(root, text=x,font=('Arial 15'))
    Items.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=W) 
H = Label(root,text='Poopoo doodoo',font=('Arial 20'))
H.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N) # Here
l1 = Label(root, text = "Number: ")
l1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W,pady=2,padx=10)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=2)
but = Button(root,text='Submit',command=p)
but.grid(row=3,column=0)
root.mainloop()

You can also keep it in column 2 but have it stick to the west, or implement any number of other solutions.
